# Different behaviour on F# module initialization

Tags: f#

I have the following F# program:

```
open MyModule

printfn "%d" test
```

With MyModule being:

```
module MyModule

printfn "foo"

let test = 
  printfn "bar"
  42
```

This produces the following output:

```
foo
bar
42
```

When I change MyModule to:

```
module MyModule

printfn "foo"

let test = 
  // printfn "bar" <-- note the comment!
  42
```

... the result is:

```
42
```

Why doesn't "foo" get printed anymore?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think section 12.5.1 of the spec, [Execution of Static Initializers](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335819006), has your answer. Quoting the relevant bits:

> the static initializer for the file is executed on first access of a value that has observable initialization

and

> All definitions have observable initialization except for the following definitions in modules:

The list that follows includes:

> Non-mutable, non-thread-local values that are bound to a simple constant expression

After commenting out the first line of `test`, it becomes a constant expression. So therefore, it no longer triggers static initialization.

**EDIT**

The spec doesn't provide the rationale for this behavior, but it's similar to C#'s. For example, in this code static initialization never occurs:

```cs
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(T.Integer);
        Console.WriteLine(T.Null);
        Console.WriteLine(T.Enum);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

static class T {
    static T() {
        Console.WriteLine("You won't see this.");
    }
    public const int Integer = 1;
    public const string Null = null;
    public const ConsoleKey Enum = ConsoleKey.Escape;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after reading it a few times I understand it. Though the behavior seems too complicated / inconsistent. For example "let test = 1+2" doesn't print "foo", while "let test = add 1 2" with add being "let add a b = a+b" does print "foo". This conforms to the language spec but still seems strange. Is there a reason why static initializers aren't just executed on first access to anything within the module, no matter if it's a simple constant expression or something else?

Comment: I've updated my answer to demonstrate that C# behaves similarly. I suppose it could be a performance optimization. Since it's impossible for a constant to depend on side-effects, or any computation for that matter, there's no apparent reason for static initialization to occur before accessing it.