# How to execute module do block?

Tags: f#

I need to do some setup in a module that I wanted to accomplish by leveraging a `do` block.  Strangely though, my `do` block never seems to get hit.

Even stranger, If I load the module code into fsi, it does get hit. Here is my example:

Main.fs

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    printfn "%b" TestNamespace.M.x
    0
```

TestModule.fs

```
namespace TestNamespace

module M = 
    do
        printfn "In do"
        failwith "Error" // this is line 6

    let x  = true
```

When I run the compiled executable I get

```
>test.exe
 true
```

Why didn't the exception get thrown? If I run the module in FSI by itself I get

```
In do
System.Exception: Error
    at <StartupCode$FSI_0006>.$FSI_0006.main@() in    C:\Projects\Personal2\Playground\fsscripts\fsscripts\TestModule.fs:line 6
Stopped due to error
```

So it got the exception.

I see that in the decompliation that the do initializers get rolled into a seperate class

```
namespace \u003CStartupCode\u0024fsscripts\u003E
{
  internal static class \u0024Library1
  {
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    internal static int init\u0040;

    static \u0024Library1()
    {
      ExtraTopLevelOperators.PrintFormatLine<Unit>((PrintfFormat<Unit, TextWriter, Unit, Unit>) new PrintfFormat<Unit, TextWriter, Unit, Unit, Unit>("In do"));
      Operators.FailWith<Unit>("Error");
      bool x = M.x;
    }
  }
}
```

VS the actual module code:

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
  [CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Module)]
  public static class M
  {
    public static bool x
    {
      [DebuggerNonUserCode] get
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So how do I make sure the do block actually gets executed?

--

Edit, given the above example counts as a simple constant expression so won't produce an observable initialization, why does the following also not work?

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 
    printfn "%d" (TestNamespace.M.x id 1)
    0
```

```
namespace TestNamespace

module M = 
    do
        printfn "In do"
        failwith "Error"

    let x f a = f a
```

This prints out `1` no problem.

---

Edit, after having re-read Tomas's comments its because a function is considered a constant expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different behaviour on F# module initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575323/different-behaviour-on-f-module-initialization)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a good explanation of the problem, see the answer to [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575323/different-behaviour-on-f-module-initialization). The important bit says:

> the static initializer for the file is executed on first access of a value that has observable initialization

Now, "observable initialization" is somewhat tricky idea, but simple constant initialization definitely does not have observable initialization - that's why the `do` block is not executed. You can trick the compiler into thinking that there is some imperative action, for example by adding `do ()`:

```
module M = 
    do
        printfn "In do"
        failwith "Error" // this is line 6

    let x = (do ()); true
```

Comment: Interesting. Would this execute every time someone calls `x`? Also if I have a module with a large amount of methods how can I guarantee that my module setup occurs without having to prepend this to every method?

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused as to the observable initialization. I have a non trivial module with lots going on it with many methods that aren't bound to simple constant expressions, and yet the initializer doesn't run

Comment: No - it is executed just once on the first access. I'm not entirely sure what is the best way to guarantee the initialization (I actually have this problem myself!), but I suppose you should be fine if the functions _use_ some values defined during the initialization...

Comment: The problem is that a function declaration does _not_ have observable behavior (it is defining just a constant value - which happens to be a function).

Comment: Let me update the question, I can reproduce this by calling in a non constant function

Comment: Oh, I misread your statement.  So if I have a module that is all function definitions, nothing will get initialized?  Even when functions are used?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You can see functions as `let f = (fun x -> ...)` and these are constant expressions...

Answer (score 2):

You can get the behavior you want, while maintaining the same public interface, with a class:

```
type M private () = 
    static do
        printfn "In do"
        failwith "Error"

    static member val x  = true
```

Comment: Nice idea, but this won't work if you expect to auto open the module and want the functions in the global space right?  In the end I created a wrapper class basically like what you have and called a function on it from another class thereby forcing the static initializer to run. Thanks!

Comment: Wonder if I can reference `M.x` from a module `do` and still have M's static constructor run? So frustrating that module do doesn't work. I need to initialize Dapper Option type handlers, and would prefer to do it without the user having to put stuff in their app startup.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a clean way to do it.

First, note that if you wanted the initialization code to run every time the function is called, you would do this:

```
module M =
    let init () =
        printfn "In init"

    let x f a =
        init ()
        printfn "In x"
        f a
```

So, if you want it to be called just once (static initialization), you can simply remove the `()` from both places:

```
module M =
    let init =
        printfn "In init"

    let x f a =
        init
        printfn "In x"
        f a
```

The nice thing is that you have documented your design that the `init` code will be called first. If you have several separate blocks of initialization code, it is clear which dependency you are relying on (although the first initialization will execute all such blocks of course).

**UPDATE**

Here is a version, which works in a Release build too. Not quite so clean, but almost:

```
module Init =
    open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

    [<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)>]
    let call init = init

module M =
    let init =
        printfn "In init"

    let x f a =
        Init.call init
        printfn "In x"
        f a
```

Note that `init` is still a `unit` value, so `Init.call` is a non-inlined function that does nothing at all. So there is the overhead of a function call to nothing.

An alternative, which also works but seems a little strange is this:

```
module M =
    let mutable init =
        printfn "In init"

    let x f a =
        init <- init
        printfn "In x"
        f a
```

Can anyone improve on this?

Comment: It works in a Debug build, but not in a Release build, presumably because the reference to 'init' gets optimized away? The "do ()" trick also does not seem to work in a Release build.